# Increment by one automatically the -"number" in if statement

Tags: python, methods, if-statement

I have a problem in Python.

How can I increment by one fully automatically the -"number" present in this if statement?

An example to understand me. I have this situation

```
def name1:
    if (dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 1] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 2] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 3] == ldictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 4] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 5]):
        blablabla

def name2:
    if (dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 1] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 2] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 3] == ldictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 4]):
        blabla

def name3:
    if (dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 1] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 2] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 3]):
        blabla
```

I repeat the same code, so how to avoid this?

Thank you

Edit: I have a normal dictonary like

```
dictonary = {"Element": ["Key1", "Key2"]}
```

I wanna have a cycle that confirm me to work with "Key1" == "Key2" case.

Comment: Is the use of ldictionary a typo?

Comment: Tell us more about your data and why you are writing these functions. These names don't tell us anything about the problem you're really trying to solve.

Comment: I have a normal dictonary like dictonary = {"Element": ["Key1", "Key2"]}
I wanna have a cycle that confirm me to work with "Key1" == "Key2" case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way:

```
if all ( [ dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 1] ==  
           dictionary[class.methodclass()][ noConstant]  
           for noConstant in range(constant - 2,  constant - 6, -1 )  ]
       ):
    blablabla
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This way return me a result for two single string, repeat for one other string. So I have a result like a write:

if ([dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 1] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant -2]):
    blablabla
if ([dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant - 1] == dictionary[class.methodclass()][constant -3]):
    blablabla

Etc... So the output is not equal to what I wanna to see.

Comment: @SniperWolf,  check for second dictionary index:  `[noConstant]`. In my answer I compare first dictionary occurrence with all others, also see `all` python function. Sorry explain your comment. I don't understand what are you talking about.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my bad english. I re-try with your solution and work very very well for me. Thank you, I discovered a new usefull solution through you.

Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The core aim I can summarize from your code is: to judge if values in certain section of a list are all the same.

According to this logic, we can write a function to archive:

```
def is_list_section_repeated(li, start, end):
    section = li[start:end]
    if section.count(section[0]) == len(section):
        return True
    return False
```

With this function your code could be:

```
def name1:
    if is_list_section_repeated(dictionary[class.methodclass()], constant - 5, constant - 1):
        blablabla

def name2:
    if is_list_section_repeated(dictionary[class.methodclass()], constant - 4, constant - 1):
        blablabla

....
```

As the situation is a kind of complex as to most common cases, I think write a function to handle it specially is better that use tricky tricks which may make code unclear and hard to read :P

Answer (score 0):

Your task has two parts:

a) You have several functions that repeat the same complex test.

Solution: If the test is complex enough, factor it out into a separate function that returns True or False. Use it in each of your nameN functions.

b) You have a test that checks whether a series of elements are all the same. Using the simple version in your edit: Given a list of dictionary keys, check that all values are the same.

Solution: Fetch all the values, form a set, and check its size:

```
tocheck = [ "Key1", "Key2" ]
values = set( mydict[k] for k in tocheck )
if len(values) == 1:
    print "equal"
else:
    print "unequal"
```

You can adapt the same approach to your original code: Write a comprehension (or any other kind of loop) that collects into a set all the values you're comparing. If you do this a lot, it'll be worth your while to set up a simple function that encapsulates this kind of test.